# Determine conservative force

Tags: vectors, physics

"Determine by appropriate calculations whether a force $\vec{F}$ acting on a particle at $\vec{r}$ from the source by the relation:
$$
\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = \frac{A}{r^2} \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}
$$
(A is a constant) is conservative or not."

I tried splitting the function into $x, y, z$ components with no success. I was hinted that I should solve it by trying a circular path and seeing if the work is indeed $0$, however I dont know how to approach it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Marvin. Would $V(r)=-A/r$, with $\vec F (\vec r) =-\nabla V(r)$ an option?

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily done in spherical co-ordinates.

see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/gradi.html#c2

for the appropriate formulas.

In your case ...
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = \vec \nabla f(\vec r)$$

where $f(r)$ is the scalar function
$$ f(\vec r)=-\frac A r   $$

So $ \vec{F}(\vec{r})$ is conservative because 
$$ \int _{\vec a} ^{\vec b} \vec{F}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec r = f(\vec b) - f(\vec a)$$

independent of path.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the path into infinitesimal segments in radial direction and infinitesimal arcs, perpendicular to the radius. Along those arcs $d\vec r$ is perpendicular to $\vec r$, so the work done is $dW=\vec F(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r=0$. Therefore the integral along any circular segment centered on origin will be $0$. So all you need to worry is the integral in the radial direction for those segments $d\vec r$ is along $\vec r$, so $dW=\frac A{r^2} dr$. When you integrate this, you will get $0$.